# Apply multiple Regular Expressions to a DataTable column

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I have a data table with a column containing Ids separated by commas. This is paired with a multi-select dropdown to filter rows. When filtering by a single Id using Regular expression, everything works fine. But now I need to filter by more than one Id. I am creating multiple regular expressions one each for every selected Id and applying them in succession to the column. But the results do not look right. Below is the code for the change handler of the multi-select dropdown where all the action is. Any help or advice is appreciated.

```
$("#skillsSearch").on("change", function () {
            var val = $("#skillsSearch").val();
            if (!val || val.toString().indexOf(-1) >= 0) {
                table.search('')
                    .columns()
                    .search('')
                    .draw();
                $("#skillsSearch")[0].sumo.unSelectAll();
                return;
            }
            @if (ViewBag.AdminView) {
                @if (includeInactive)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 9;");
                } else
                {
                    @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 8;");
                }
            } else
            {
                @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 5;");
            }
            var searchTerms = val.toString().split(',');
            var regexPattern = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
                regexPattern += '(^,?' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?\\D)|(,?\\D' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?\\D)|(,?\\D' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?$)';
                var tb = table.columns(columnNdx)
                    .search(regexPattern, true, false);
                    
                regexPattern = "";
            }
            tb.draw();
            
});
```

Comment: Is there a tag missing from this question? Possibly `asp.net` or `asp.net-mvc`?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching around, I came across a post where someone advised creating my own Search Plugin ... He pointed to a blog at [DataTables Site Blog](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-08-26) ... It took a bit of effort but it worked just like I wanted it to ... Below is the code I came with to implement the desired behavior, in case somebody else lands here ...

```
        $("#skillsSearch").on("change", function () {
            table.draw();
        });
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, searchData) {
            var val = $("#skillsSearch").val();
            if (!val) {

                return true;
            }
            @if (ViewBag.AdminView) {
                @if (includeInactive)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 9;");
                } else
                {
                    @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 8;");
                }
            } else
            {
                @Html.Raw("var columnNdx = 5;");
            }
            var searchTerms = val.toString().split(',');
            var regexPattern = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
                regexPattern = '(^,?' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?\\D)|(,?\\D' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?\\D)|(,?\\D' + +searchTerms[i] + ',?$)';

                var match = searchData[columnNdx].match(regexPattern);
                if (!match) return false;
                regexPattern = "";
            }
            return true;

        });
```